# Nginx proxy_pass stoped working when I was configuring error pages

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I was trying to make a 500 error page for a situation when server behind proxy when is *off* and a 404 error page for not found static pages.

I already had working `proxy_pass` to `localhost:8080` for `messenger` but while working on adding custom error pages I had to mess something up and it stopped working. Error pages are working all well but `mydomain.d/messenger/` returns `404 19` (I know it from logs) but doesn't return the custom page.

```
erver {
        server_name     mydomain.d;


        # newly added
        location / {
                proxy_pass "http://localhost:8081/";
        }


        # newly added
        location /webapp/planner/ {
                proxy_pass "http://localhost:8082/";
        }

        # was working for some time
        location /messenger/ {
                proxy_pass "http://localhost:8080/";
        }

        # newly added
        location /static/ {
                alias /home/static/;
        }

        # newly added
        error_page 404 /err404.html;
        location = /err404.html {
                root /home/server/errors/err404;
        }

        # newly added 
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /err500.html;
        location = /err500.html {
                root /home/server/errors/err500;
        }
        ...
```

I changed only this config while making the error pages. 
`curl localhost:8080/messenger/xxx` gives expected output. 
`https://mydomain.d/messenger/xxx` redirects me to: 
`https://mydomain.d/xxx` with `404 error` page.


So in summary: When configuring error pages for static file access and for situations when servers behind proxy is down I accidentally broke `proxy_pass` access to `/messenger/` which now only returns an `404 19` error.


What is the fix?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I tried to explain myself a bit better. I might have been posting too late and now I see how ambiguous question was. Could you look at it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem:

There was an unnecessary `/` at the end of `proxy_pass` address. 
Wrong:

```
        location /messenger/ {
                proxy_pass "http://localhost:8080/";
        }
```

Right:

```
        location /messenger/ {
                proxy_pass "http://localhost:8080"; #<-- here the '/' at end is gone
        }
```